# Stencil config generating files in dist that doesn't work standalone

Tags: web-component, stenciljs

I have started on stencil development and tried to create the hello world from it but while trying to build and deploy and use it stand alone the dist file is generating some random files which doesn't seem to work standalone.

I have published the files to npm and trying to run it standalone in a html file. Using unpkg
https://unpkg.com/browse/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.2/dist/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <my-component first="FF" last="'Don't call me a framework' JS"></my-component>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/rahulrsingh09-stenciltest2@0.0.2/dist/index.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this one is a test from a different package i found in npm and this seems to work .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  
</head>

<body>

 <my-component first="FF" last="'Don't call me a framework' JS"></my-component>

<script src='https://unpkg.com/web-component-stencil-test@0.0.1/dist/test.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The only difference i found is https://unpkg.com/browse/web-component-stencil-test@0.0.1/dist/

the dist contains a root file for the main of project which runs standalone but this is not generated in the new stencil config build. the documentation on this is very sparse , can some one point me what am i doing wrong.. here or something missing by stencil.

**package.json**

```
"name": "stenciltest2",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Stencil Component Starter",
  "main": "dist/index.cjs.js",
  "module": "dist/custom-elements/index.js",
  "es2015": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "es2017": "dist/esm/index.mjs",
  "types": "dist/custom-elements/index.d.ts",
  "collection": "dist/collection/collection-manifest.json",
  "collection:main": "dist/collection/index.js",
  "unpkg": "dist/test/test.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/",
    "loader/"
  ],
```

**stencil config**

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  namespace: 'test',
  buildEs5: true,
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },
    {
      type: 'dist-custom-elements-bundle',
    },
    {
      type: 'docs-readme',
    },
    {
      type: 'www',
      serviceWorker: null, // disable service workers
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "standalone" as in, without an http server?

If so, this is what the Ionic team calls "prerender."

```
stencil build --prerender
```

You will need to set `baseUrl` in `stencil.config.ts`.

```
import { Config } from '@stencil/core';

export const config: Config = {
  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'www',
      baseUrl: 'https://somedomain.com/somepath',
    }
  ]
};
```

See:

- https://stenciljs.com/docs/prerender-config
- https://stenciljs.com/docs/www
- https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/master/stencil.config.ts

Comment: I think what he asked is not prerender, but how to load custom component generated from stencil directly in a browser. Which is not working correctly from stencil starter.

Answer (score 0):

By defining `esmLoaderPath` in stencil.config you ask stencil to build a separate loader-package into the loader folder.

This results in two different packages!

Using the content in the loader package you can run `defineCustomElements` on window.

after having this call, your custom web-components are mapped / interpreted by the browser.